# Missing praying due to family

Tags: salat, allah

I just wanted to say that I am a teenage girl who is a muslim. I have not been very close to allah but I’m trying to get closer now. I started praying as much as I can and I even started learning more about islam. However, my mom is not muslim and is not very fond of me being very religious.  I try to pray before she comes home everyday so that she doesn’t find out. I am really scared to go to hell and I’m trying to do what’s right and serve allah. Please advice me on what to do. I tried speaking to her about it but she seemed unhappy. I know that respecting your parents is important in islam but obeying allah is important too. Please help me.
Thank you for taking the time and reading this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Salaam,
Allah (swt) knows your struggles and intentions, and loves how hard you are trying to get closer to your faith. There are three forms of prayers: salat (the five daily), zhikr ( rhythmic repetition of the name of God), and simply making dua. You can even make dua in your head. Pray to Allah (swt) that your mom is more understanding of your faith, but also give it time because everything happens with patience. :) Islam is simple and beautiful so remember that God knows all our situations, and I promise that it will improve over time. When I first taught my siblings to pray the five prayers, I started them with just a couple and I increased it overt time because I know that Allah knows their situation, and now they do all five. Keep going and remain strong:) hope that helps!
MuslimGap